# Multiple projects in a Visual Studio solution with same dependencies produce different pdb sizes

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, pdb-files

I have a single Visual Studio Solution containing 170 projects. Most of these projects are used as dependencies for a couple of main projects.

These main projects include a full version and a lite version. Lets say product_full_link and product_lite_link.

These two projects have the same project dependencies and only differ in configuration by slightly limiting the available features between programs.

When I build the solution, it builds product_full_link and then product_lite_link. The .pdb file for product_full_link ends up somewhere around ~1GB. The .pdb file for product_lite_link gets to about ~4GB before getting an error message.

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1201: error writing to program database 'C:\project\Debug\product_lite_link.pdb'; check for insufficient disk space, invalid path, or insufficient privilege
```

All linker options are the same between these projects. I've tried using multiple link options to reduce .pdb size including all methods described here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/03/05/shrink-my-program-database-pdb-file/ to no avail.

I've also tried to build the product_lite_link project independently of the product_full_link project and it still results in the huge .pdb file and produces the same error message, while the product_full_link project always builds successfully with a managable .pdb.

Any help or references for managing multi-project solutions would help greatly.

Comment: You say the **code** in both two projects are same?

Comment: Yes the code is the same. They differ in their preprocessor directives that limit the available features in the lite version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question.

The issue is that the linker options were different between projects.

These were the linker options in my product_full_link.vcxproj

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
  <Link>
    <AdditionalDependencies>product_full_configuration_d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    <HeapReserveSize>0x10000000</HeapReserveSize>
    <HeapCommitSize>0x10000</HeapCommitSize>
    <LargeAddressAware>true</LargeAddressAware>
    <ShowProgress>NotSet</ShowProgress>
    <TargetMachine>MachineX64</TargetMachine>
    <GenerateDebugInformation>DebugFull</GenerateDebugInformation>
    <FullProgramDatabaseFile>true</FullProgramDatabaseFile>
  </Link>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

These were the linker options in my product_lite_link.vcxproj

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
  <Link>
    <AdditionalDependencies>product_full_configuration_d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    <TargetMachine>MachineX64</TargetMachine>
  </Link>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

The issue is that in the options in **Visual Studio > Project Properties > Linker** were not showing the same options that were in the .vcxproj file so I was unable to identify the differences there.

I'm not sure though, which of these options is responsible in the reduction of the .pdb filesize.